# How to delete files which contain words in the iOS documentsDirectory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdocumentdirectory

I want to delete several image files in the documentsDirectory. There are already a large number of files in the documents directory, but I only want to delete the files which contain the word "Test" in their filename.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: I haven't yet, because I am unsure of what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple. Have a look at [`[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which lists you all the files in the specified directory. Then you could filter/iterate the array according to your needs.

To delete a file use `[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]`.